# counter value is incrementing just once in if else condition inside while loop

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

The purpose of the code below is

1. Scan the Location of the bot
2. Scan the state of the location, whether it is dirty or clean
3. Do this continuously until the bot get 3 times "no" state continuously

The issue is:
counter value increment just once, `counter = 1`, and then never increment. That's why the loop never ends.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char location[4];
    char state[4];
    int count=0;

    //If the bot get state "no" 3 times continuosly, end the loop.
    while(count<3){

        //Scan bot location
        printf("Bot Location ?\n");                 
        scanf("%s",location);

        if(strcmp(location, "a")==0){
            printf("Is it dirty?\n");
            //Scan state of the location, dirty or clean (yes or no)
            scanf("%s",state);

            if(strcmp(state,"yes")==0){

                //Reset the counter value to zero if state is yes
                count=0;

                //printing the counter value
                printf("Value of Counter %d \n",count);
                printf("Clean\n");
                printf("Go left to B\n");
            }
            else if (strcmp(state,"no")==0) {
                printf("Go Left to B\n");

                //Counter increment if state is no
                count++;
                printf("Value of Counter %d \n",count);
            }
            else {
                printf("Wrong input\n");
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(location, "b")==0){
            printf("Is B dirty?\n");
            scanf("%s",state);

            if(strcmp(state,"yes")==0){

                //Reset the counter value to zero if state is yes, same as Location A
                count=0;
                printf("Clean\n");
                printf(" Go Right to A\n");
                printf("Value of Counter %d \n",count); 
            }
            else if (strcmp(state,"no")==0) {
                printf("Go Right to A\n");

                //Counter increment if state is no, same as Location A
                count++;
                printf("Value of Counter %d \n",count);
            }
            else {
                printf("Wrong input\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Location not found\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `count` is unintialized. `char location[1];` is useless(in this context) - `scanf("%s",&state);` ---> `scanf("%s",state);`

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Yes count was uninitialized and not a big deal here I think.
 I am using strcmp, so location[1] is required here.

Comment: I will provide an answer when I get time.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate that..

Comment: You cannot use `"%s"` with an array of length 1.  The format means "skip white space, then read one or more non-white-space characters into a null terminated string", and an array of length 1 does not have enough space for both a character and a null byte.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. You are right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of problems:-

- `count` is uninitialized. So when you use it in the while loop - what value it has to which you are comparing the other variable. You don't know - it is unspecified. You should initialize it with `0` outside the loop.
- `char location[1]` Maybe you thought you need a single character input and a `char*` to pass to the `strcmp`? Well clear few things - `strcmp` expects a null terminated `char` array. Here suppose you get `y` or some input in `input` but is there any `\0` here? No. You didn't leave any space for that.
  Solution is to make `input` array larger. `char input[4]` maybe.
- `&input` and `input` is quite different. For array type first has type `char(*)[]` (pointer pointing to an array) and second is a pointer to `char`. `scanf` expects a `char*` when you use `%s` format specifier. You didn't provide one.
- Add error check when using those `scanf`-s. Check the return value of `scanf` and if it fails print it and exit.

  ```
   if(scanf("%3s",input)!=1){
     fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
     exit(1);
   }
  ```

Comment: Thank you. 
I have already made the suggested edit. But the problem is still there.

Comment: @TuhinA..: What error do you get? Can I be sure that your code logic is bullet proof?

Comment: No error, if your run the code, you will get that the counter value is always 1 after getting state "no". counter value should increase every time it get state as "no"

Comment: @TuhinA..: Tell me the input you gave. It works for me as intended. You checked it correctly?

Comment: input for location, "a" or "b"
input for state, "yes" or "no"
3 times "no" should end the loop

Comment: @TuhinA..: It ended for me. Check it carefully.

Comment: Thanks it's working now!!
It was the location array size issue! great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the string.h header.
Try add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

at the top of the code

Comment: It is one (minor) problem.  It is far from the only problem with the code.

Comment: The program doesn't increment the count variable because strcmp doesn't work and the loop never ends. I can't find any other problems

Comment: This is not issue @CarloLonghi . I have made the change. Thanks anyway